# Calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t^2} dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm thinking of using the residue theorem. The residues are at $\pm i$ and I know how to calculate them but I'm stuck on finding a contour that fits? How do you find the correct contour in general?

Comment: How about half of circle of diameter $0$ and $R$?

Comment: The antiderivative exists in elementary functions: $\ln$ and $\arctan$.

Comment: $f(t)=1/(1+t^2)$ has the Mellin transform,
$$\phi(s)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{s-1}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\ dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)$$
take $s=3/2$,
$$\phi(3/2)=\frac{\pi}{2}\csc\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}.$$

Comment: The transformation can be proved by first evaluating the Mellin transform of $1/(1+t)$ using the substitution $1+t=1/(1-x)$ and some Beta function properties. Then use the relation,
$$\mathcal{M}\{f(t^a);s\}=\frac{\phi(s/a)}{a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the integral without the residus theorem. Indeed,

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt t}{1 + t^2}\mathrm d t &= \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt t}{1 + t^2}\mathrm d t + \int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt t}{1 + t^2}\mathrm d t\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt t}{1 + t^2}\mathrm d t + \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt {\frac1u}}{1 + \frac1{u^2}} \frac1{u^2}\mathrm d t\\
&= \int_{0}^1 \frac{\sqrt t + \frac1{\sqrt t}}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt\\
&= 2\int_{0}^1 \frac{1+t^2}{1+t^4}\mathrm d t\\
&= 2 \left[\frac1{\sqrt 2}\left(\arctan \left(t\sqrt 2 + 1\right) + \arctan \left(t\sqrt 2 - 1\right)\right)\right]\\
&= \ldots
\end{align}

$$$$